# How do I format an IFS statement if the logical test include intervals such as 5 < x < 7?

Tags: excel

I want to use this formula to select a value or string depending on a cells value.

```
=IFS(I2<36000,"D-0010", 36000 < I2 < 46800, "D-1013", 46800 < I2 < 57600, "D- 
1316", 57600 < I2 < 68400, "D-1619", 68400 < I2 < 86400, "D-1900")
```

So if the value in the cell is 50,000 the output should be D-1316 but I am unsure how to setup the intervals.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that IFS() resolves serially.  In other words as soon as it finds the first TRUE it stops, with that we can simplify:

```
=IFS(I2<36000,"D-0010", I2 < 46800, "D-1013",I2 < 57600, "D-1316", I2 < 68400, "D-1619", I2 < 86400, "D-1900")
```

But to answer your question, you would do an AND() with two criteria.

```
AND(36000 < I2, I2 < 46800)
```

---

Another option:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(I2,{0,36000,46800,57600,68400}),"D-0010",  "D-1013", "D-1316", "D-1619",  "D-1900")
```

Comment: It may also be helpful to use <= and >=.  Otherwise if you have a the number 46800, it will ever be true, as the formula is only looking for anything greater or less than it.