# Non-intuitive Comparison Behavior

Tags: excel

In Excel, why does this return FALSE?

```
= 3 < 4 < 5
```

… but this returns TRUE?

```
= 3 > 4 > 5
```

Comment: Probably it calculates it from right to left, ie `3 < (4<5) = 3 < 1`, `3 > (4>5) = 3 > 0`

Comment: I'm sure you're right.  This is a common stumbling block for newcomers to Excel or programming languages, because they expect it to work the way they learned in math class.

Comment: It might be the way that booleans are represented and displayed in Excel. You'll also notice that `=TRUE<5` is `FALSE` even though we anticipate that `TRUE` and `1` are equivalent. Instead `=INT(3<4)<5` does what you would anticipate. It forces our expected order of operation AND converts the boolean `TRUE` value into its integer representation of `1` which then makes the next inequality work the way we anticipate it should. When in doubt, be more explicit with your code.

Comment: @JNevill, good point.  Booleans (true or false) are always greater than numbers in Excel.

Comment: @IłyaBursov, I believe Excel calculates left to right.  So `(3 < 4) < 5` would be `TRUE < 5`.  Since booleans are always greater than numbers, this returns FALSE.  Likewise, `(3 > 4) > 5` would become `FALSE > 5`.  FALSE is a boolean, therefore the result is TRUE.

Comment: @RickHitchcock yeah, looks so

Comment: So the question is essentially, Why are Booleans greater than numbers in Excel, or is that just to maintain backward compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3?

Comment: A Boolean is like light, it is two things in one, both text and number and depending on its use is what it becomes, but we need to do specific things to it to make it a number.  For example `="1"=1` will return `FALSE` but `=--"1"=1` will return `TRUE` as the `--` forces the string to a number.  Same with TRUE/FALSE,  `=--TRUE=1` will return TRUE` but `=TRUE=1` returns FALSE.

Comment: Nice, @ScottCraner, was hoping you'd join in.  It was your response here that got me thinking about this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60403721/3903374